# ObservableObjectに準拠しているクラスは複数Viewで参照が共有されるのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, swiftui

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input
こちらのチュートリアルを実施していて疑問ができたので質問します。

【背景】
以下のようにObservableObjectに準拠するクラスを作成します

- UserData.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @Published var landmarks = landmarkData
}
```

それを利用するViewを二つ作成します。

- LandmarkList.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites only")
                }
                ...
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
...
```

- LandmarkDetail.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    var landmark: Landmark
    
    var landmarkIndex: Int {
        userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    ...
                    Button(action: {
                        self.userData.landmarks[self.landmarkIndex].isFavorite.toggle()
                    }) {
                        if self.userData.landmarks[self.landmarkIndex].isFavorite {
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "star")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
    ...            
    }
}
...
```

このようにした際にLandmarkDetailのButtonでisFavoriteを更新して戻ると、LandmarkListの方でも更新が反映されています。

【お聞きしたいこと】

- この挙動を見るとLandmarkListとLandmarkDetailで参照しているuserDataが同一インスタンスに見えるのですが、その認識で合っていますか？
- 別Viewで参照したものが同インスタンスなのは気持ち悪いので、@BindingでLandmarkListからLandmarkDetailにObservableObjectに準拠させたLandmarkを渡す方が自然な気がするのですが、このような実装(上記のチュートリアルのような実装)はよくあるのでしょうか？ Appleのチュートリアルがこれなのでそういうものなのかな？と思うのですが。。

不勉強なためそもそも勘違いの気もするので、間違いがあったら修正いたします。
以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> この挙動を見るとLandmarkListとLandmarkDetailで参照しているuserDataが同一インスタンスに見えるのですが、その認識で合っていますか？

はい。

> 別Viewで参照したものが同インスタンスなのは気持ち悪い

「気持ち悪い」と言う極度に主観的な表現に対しては、お答えできる内容はありません。例えばどのような弊害がありうると思われているのか、もう少し技術的な観点から疑念・疑問などを明確化していただければ何かお答えできることがあるかもしれません。

> @BindでLandmarkListからLandmarkDetailにObservableObjectに準拠させたLandmarkを渡す

「@Bind」と言うのは、`@Binding`のことでしょうか？だとしたら、参照型のインスタンスを`@Binding`で修飾された変数に持つというのが意味を持つことは殆どありません。全くもって不自然な記述です。「参照型」と「インスタンスの生成」について、十分理解出来ていないのではないかと思います。

---

> ObservableObjectに準拠しているクラスは複数Viewで参照が共有されるのでしょうか？

「`ObservableObject`に準拠している」かどうかには全く関わりなく、(参照型である)クラスのインスタンスを保持する変数は、同じインスタンスが渡されていれば共有されますし、別のインスタンスを生成して渡せば共有はされていないと言うことになります。

`@EnvironmentObject`と言うのは、いわば「同一のインスタンスを共有しやすくするための仕組み」であり、リンク先のチュートリアルで言えば、SceneDelegate.swift の17行目、

```
.environmentObject(UserData())
```

ここで生成された`UserData`のインスタンスを`LandmarkList`配下のViewで共有してもらうために、`environmentObject`を呼んでいます。

---

この辺はSwiftUIについては、典型的なパターンですが、

- 画面に反映させたい状態をプロパティに持つクラスを`ObservableObject`に準拠させる
- それらのプロパティには`@Published`を指定する
- それらのプロパティでUIを更新したいViewは`@ObservedObject`(または`@StateObject`か`@EnvironmentObject`を指定して、そのクラスのインスタンスを保持するプロパティを保持する

と言う手順を取ります。「`ObservableObject`に準拠させる」と言うのは、同一インスタンスを共有するための仕組みではなく、「クラスのプロパティの変化を画面に反映させる」ための仕組みと言えます。

---

何かわかりにくい点があれば、コメント等していただけるようお願いします。

Comment: "「気持ち悪い」と言う極度に主観的な表現"→主観的で不適切な表現をしてしまい申し訳ありません。classが参照型なのはわかりますが、別ファイルで利用されている(別のタイミングでインスタンス化される)のに同じ参照を持っていることに違和感を覚えました。ただこの内容については”@EnvironmentObjectと言うのは..."以下の内容でわかりました。それぞれインスタンス化されているのではなく、SceneDelegate.swiftでインスタンス化されてそのインスタンスが入るという理解をしました。また"「参照型」と「インスタンスの生成」について、十分理解出来ていないのではないかと思います。"についてこちらもその通りですね。。structで宣言した型を受け渡し、変更を監視する時にそうしていたので、混同していました。この内容間違っていたらご指摘いただけると助かります。大変丁寧な解説ありがとうございます。

Comment: @tbt さん、「主観的」な内容が質問や回答に入ること自体が不適切と言っているのではなく、質問の主文自体はできるだけ具体的にしていただいた方が良いと言う趣旨だったのですが、私の表現の方が逆に不適切だったかもしれません。コメント内容を見る限り十分ご理解いただいているようなのですが、失礼しました。「structで宣言した型を受け渡し、変更を監視する時にそうしていた」この辺はその通りで、値型であるstructの場合には、大元と考えられるViewに`@State`で変数を宣言し、他のViewではそのBindingを使ってその値にアクセスすると言うのは、非常に基本的なSwiftUIのパターンの一つです。同じやり方がclassの場合にはうまくいかない、と言うのを経験するのはSwiftUIの学習中には非常によくあることのようで、Appleのdeveloper forumsに類似の質問がちょくちょくあがったりしています。質問文からどの程度SwiftUIの基本を理解しているかよく読み取れなかったので、この回答のような表現になってしまいましたが、ポイントとなる事項はご理解いただけたようでほっとしています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。SwiftUIの実装パターンがケース毎に色々あってこんがらがっていました。ご回答のおかげで多少自分の中で整理できたので、実際に色々試しつつ身につけていきます。